# Getting value of arbitrary form element in Google Apps Script web app

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a Google Apps Script web app which has a form attached, for example:

```
<form id="form">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="3" name="mb1" value="0">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="3" name="mb2" value="0">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="3" name="mb3" value="0">
    etc...
    <input id="submit" type="submit" style="display: none" onclick="this.value='Submitting ...'; google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(formSubmitted) .writeForm(this.parentNode); return false;">
</form>
```

The Code.gs file has a writeForm(form) function, which can access the form input values like so:

```
var mb1 = form.mb1;
var mb2 = form.mb2;
etc...
```

However, this approach is inefficient with many such inputs (I have around 80). Much better would just be to get the values when they're being processed in a loop, like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 80; i++) {
    var formItemID = "mb"+i;
    console.log(form.formItemID);
}
```

However, this of course does not work, as it looks for form inputs with the id "formItemID". I've taken a look at some functionality of the HTMLFormElements class which should be being sent, but Apps Script doesn't seem to implement this fully, and I can't find documentation of the form.ItemName property. Is there a way to achieve this functionality without calling for each form input separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side, Your form is sent as a [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) with key as input name and  value as input values. Your `form` will look like:

```
{
 mb1:0,
 mb2:1,
 mb3:0
}
```

To access the values, You can use `form.mb1` as you've used or `form['mb1']`. To use variables as keys, always use the bracket `[]` notation

```
for(var i = 0; i <= 80; i++) {
    var formItemID = "mb"+i;
    console.log(form[formItemID]);//Note bracket notation 
}
```

Or without a for loop,

```
var valuesArr = Object.keys(form).map(function(key){return form[key];})
```

Comment: Perfect! This works without me having to restructure any other code.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just loop through the form elements and get the input values.  This will send an array to the server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form" name="form">
      <input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="3" value="0">
      <input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="3" value="0">
      <input class="range" type="range" min="0" max="3" value="0">
      <br>
      <input id="button" type="button" onclick="onClick()">
    </form>
    <script>
      function onClick() {
        var form = document.getElementById("form");
        var vals = [];
        for( var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++ ) {
          if( form.elements[i].className === "range" ) {
            vals.push(form.elements[i].value);
          }
        }
        google.script.run.getForm(vals);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```